# list of supported operations on tensorflow post training quantization

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am looking to compress/optimise my tensorflow NN model following tensorflow-lite's [post training quantization](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization) guild, I am using Tensorflow 1.13.1 (NON GPU)

However, when I use the convert function I've met with a lot of error messages:

```
ConverterError: TOCO failed. See console for info.
2019-05-02 11:31:10.209374: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-05-02 11:31:10.217858: I  tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-05-02 11:31:10.217893: I  tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-05-02 11:31:10.217905: I  tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-05-02 11:31:10.217939: I  tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayScatterV3
2019-05-02 11:31:10.217961: I  tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-05-02 11:31:10.217971: I  tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-05-02 11:31:10.217979: I  tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-05-02 11:31:10.217988: I  tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
......
2019-05-02 11:31:10.223877: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before Removing unused ops: 236 operators, 384 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-05-02 11:31:10.226115: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] After Removing unused ops pass 1: 226 operators, 368 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-05-02 11:31:10.229770: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before general graph transformations: 226 operators, 368 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-05-02 11:31:10.232686: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] After general graph transformations pass 1: 177 operators, 280 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-05-02 11:31:10.235370: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before dequantization graph transformations: 177 operators, 280 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-05-02 11:31:10.237009: F tensorflow/lite/toco/tooling_util.cc:627] Check failed: dim >= 1 (0 vs. 1)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Having Googled/SO around it seems this is because not all tensorflow operaions are supported by tf-lite. My model has customised operations such as attention, biLSTM etc.

How do I know which NN architectures are supported? For the errors I received, how do I know where is the source of the problem?  e.g.

```
Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
```

what is this 20 refers to?

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is in **ConvertDataType()** function [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f0fba04cd274e7ffa24ab8e49f888ef6974e6f7a/tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc#L193).

The unsupported datatype **20** is

[38](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/types.proto#L38): `DT_RESOURCE = 20;`